# How can I increase the height of the Navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to use mostly bootstrap for a webpage and I'd like to increase the elements of the Navbar. Has anyone a suggestion for me how to do so?

```
    .navbar {
  min-height:100px;
}
```

when I do it like so, the clickable elements remain the same size.

any suggeston to scale it?

thank you for your help

Comment: Don't try to increase the height of the box, you have to increase the elements themselves.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't increase the size of inner elements just by increasing the height of the navbar.

You have to do it  either like this--

```
.navbar .navbar-nav > li > a {
line-height: 45px;
 }
```

or like this

```
.navbar .navbar-nav > li > a {
padding: 27px 15px;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much! - it's great to get help so fast

Comment: Welcome to SO. If it has helped you you can accept the answer. That's how SO works.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
.navbar {
  min-height: 200px !important;
  height: 200px !important;
  max-height: 200px !important;
}

or

.navbar {
  min-height: 200px !important;
  height: 200px !important;
  max-height: 200px !important;  
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: better on the css bottom or html web page bottom

Comment: You cannot see that as far as I know.

Comment: Sory but  i dont know about it

Comment: I'm joking dude. No need to apologize.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136660/discussion-between-tariq-b-and-breakermind).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just increase the size of a `navbar` in **Bootstrap** by directly targeting the parent element by css.

In order to increase the height of the `navbar`, you have to increase the size of the children `> li > a`. Keep in mind that the children already have vertical padding of 15px.

```
.navbar .navbar-nav > li > a {height: 100px; //Whatever you are targetting}
```

Comment: Really? A downvote without any reasonable explanation. -_-